# Android: List Adapter update view of element

Tags: android, baseadapter

I have a grid view with an Adapter class extending `BaseAdapter`. When the user clicks on one element of the grid, a new activity is launched, and in this activity, the user can changes some properties of the element. When the user back to the activity with the grid, the view only updates when it goes off the screen and comes back. I have try with `collectionViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`
but it doesn't work.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to update the view as soon as the user get back to the activity with the grid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the activity with a grid view is `ActivityA` and the other one is `ActivityB`. When user clicks on one element of the grid, from `ActivityA`, you should start `ActivityB` using `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`. Then in ActivityB, after user finished changing some properties of the element, you can call `setResult(RESULT_OK)` and finish `ActivityB`. Then `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` of `ActivityA` will be called. Here, you can check and update your grid view if the `resultCode` is `RESULT_OK`.